# How to print a Unicode text file by command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, printing, unicode, utf-8

I have a problem with printing a text file from windows command prompt to network printers. Everything works fine when my file just contains ASCII characters, but Unicode characters appear as question marks (?) on the sheet. 
Here it is the command:

```
print /d:\\{printer local ip}\{printer name} c:\text_file.txt
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: [TechNet article on Print](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731623(v=ws.10).aspx) makes it seem like its a pretty old command so it might simply be unaware of unicode. Alternatively it might not be able to send unicode in the proper format or your printer might not be able to properly handle it. What does it actually print if you hand it some unicode?

Comment: Every non-English letter will be shown as a question mark (?) on the sheen. What you mean by "old command"? Is there another command can be used instead?

Comment: If you look at the technet article its relevant as far back as Windows XP/Windows 2000. So it might just have not been updated. Unicode wasn't that well supported back then. If only special (compound or non ASCII) characters show up as question marks it might have to do how the application talks to the printer. You likely won't be able to change that behavior.